# Bootstrap navbar adjust div margin that is next to dynamic div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, width, navbar

I have a div that does not collapse in mobile view (always visible), but it is causing issues on larger displays when collapsible-links are present (as shown below).

[image]

Is there a way to make the collapsible links appear to the left of dynamic (userInfo) div? *Trying to find a css solution, so angular/javascript would be the last resort.*

Examples of desired effect:

[image]

```
<div class="navbar-header">
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
  <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>

<a class="navbar-brand" href=""><img src="http://placehold.it/599x255&text=Logo"></a>
<h4 class="navbar-text" id="navbarTitle">This is my navbar title</h4>

<ul class="nav" id="userInfo"> <!-- Dynamic -->
  <li class="dropdown pull-right">
    <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user icon-right"></span><b>{{empName}}</b>
      <b class="caret"></b>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="/logout" title="Logout"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out icon-right"></span>Logout </a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out icon-right"> Dropdown<span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <!--<li><a href="" id="logoutBtn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out icon-right"></span>Logout</a></li>-->
</ul>
</div>
```

[**Plnkr Demo**](https://plnkr.co/edit/yqVRK07ML1dVj6jDcg2e?p=preview) || [**JSFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/eveu66tf/)

**Edit** (End-result rephrasing):

I would like the links inside the div with class 'nav navbar-nav navbar-right' to always be left of the div with id 'userInfo'.

Comment: Your demo does not work and it is unclear what it is you want.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith It is working from my end, but I added a fiddle to the post. I would like links inside the div with class 'nav navbar-nav navbar-right' to always be left of the div with id 'userInfo'. I hope that makes it clear. Let me know if it doesn't.